# Create-react-app scss code compilation to css

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, node-sass

I'm currently using create-react-app for a project. CRA already support SASS and it only required node-sass installation which I have done. 
The compiled CSS is being injected into the head in a  tag.

Is there a way to change that to be compiled to a CSS filed and load it in my head with a link tag to the stylesheet?

For some reason I didn't have to do this on a previous project using the same boilerplate I am using. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can integrate React with Gulp, and then use Gulp to chose how / where the Sass gets compiled.

Comment: Yeah I thought about using that but for some reason it works the way I wanted to be in my production but in development it is not. It renders the css in style tag in my head in Dev mode and in a css file in production with a stylesheet link to it.